# Prove that product of $L_1$ norms is greater than $1$

Tags: measure-theory

If $f,g$ are non-negative functions  on a measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ such that $\mu(X)=1$ and $fg \geq 1$ a.e, prove that

$$
\left(\int f \ d\mu\right) \left(\int g \ d\mu\right) \geq 1.
$$

Can anyone provide a useful hint to approach this ?

Comment: Apply Cauchy schwartz to $\sqrt{fg}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Holder's inequality for $p=q=2$ which is called Scwartz inequality.